# AudioKit microphone permission

Tags: ios, audiokit

My AudioKit 4.5 iOS app does **not** require use of the microphone. I am setting the session type to *playback*. Whenever I launch the app, however, I am presented with an alert asking me for permission to access the microphone. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this only happens on Simulator. On device seems like it is ok.